# A Gaussian process that is not Markov with regard to its own filtration?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-process, stochastic-analysis

Is it possible to have a continuous Gaussian process that is not Markov with regard to its own filtration ? If so, can you give a non-trivial explicit example ?

Comment: https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/1127097?journalCode=tprbau

Comment: Thank you for the paper! Can we build such process using Brownian motion(s) ?